# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for updating Session variable

Tags: java

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Map.replace(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    iland.client.ClientAction.update(ClientAction.java:82)
```

My code in action

```
dao.update(cl);
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.replace("client", cl);
```

here `cl` is a

```
Client cl = new Client();
```

I am updating my database with client object and after update i am updating session variable with code

```
session.replace("client", cl);
```

This code is working properly in my local host but after deploying in server it is showing above exception.

How to resolve this?

Comment: `Map#replace` is in java since 1.8.

Comment: Does the server and your localhost run the exact same setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method named `replace()` in session map (or Map in generate till java 7). 
You just have to do

```
  dao.update(cl);
  Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
  session.put("client", cl);
```

Maps work that way, If key is present, `put(key, value)`will just overwrite the value else it'll create a new entry.

Comment: Yes, there is. :) Since 1.8 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't know that, but `put` works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

[replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-) wasn't added until java 8, but you can use `put` instead to do the same thing. [From official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)):

```
V put(K key, V value)

Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation).
If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.
(A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Map.replace()` method is only since java 1.8 i guess, check the jdk version of your server